# У пользователя должно быть два идентификатора

Tags: java, dao

В rest api один из методов должен возвращать пользователя в виде пары ключей: открытый/закрытый. Причем как открытый, так и закрытый ключ должен идентифицировать пользователя.
И сейчас у меня имеется DAO интерфейс, в котором реализованы методы `find` и `exists` для обоих видов ID. То есть вот так: `findBySecretKey, findByPublicKey, existsBySecretKey, existsByPublicKey`. Можно ли это как-то упростить?

Answer (score 2):

Передавайте оба ключа параметром, по ним вы можете получить пользователя. Только пара ключей может принадлежать одному пользователю. Если у пользователя есть другие ключи то они могут идентифицировать других пользователей.

Comment: Создать класс для id?

Comment: да, так наверное даже лучше будет